# What are pixels?

Tags: qgis

Every time I try to use a suitable scale to properly represent a district along with a suitable cartogram on the layout page, either the districts get enormously magnified or the size of the bar graphs get minimized. What should I do to do away with this problem and thereby maintain a parity?

Comment: Your title asks about pixels, but you don't mention them in your question. See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel) for an answer to the question "What are pixels?"

Comment: More readings, about the screen resolution and printing:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch

Answer (score 3):

The answer to "what is a pixel" will not help you here.  Set you scale to suit the cartogram and then use the various controls for the bar chart separately to control its size.  If the size units of 'pixels' is not working for you, then try mm or points in conjunction with 'bar length' (size tab) or 'bar width' (rendering tab).  This will let you control the size of the charts separately to the scale of your map.